# Proof that the quotient of equal rank free abelian groups is finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a free abelian group with finite rank and $H$ be a subgroup of $H$ such that $rank(G)=rank(H)$.

Then, why is $G/H$ finite?

Since $G/H$ is finitely generated, there is a free abelian group $L$ and a finite abelian group $F$ such that $G/H\cong L\times F$. Why should $L$ be of rank $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nontorsion element of $G/H$ could be pulled back to $G$ and then adjoined to a maximal $\mathbb{Z}$-independent subset of $H$ to get a bigger $\mathbb{Z}$-independent subset of $G$ (prove this), a contradiction.

Finitely-generated torsion abelian implies finite.

Comment: Aha i get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the basic theorem (part of the subject of f.g. abelian groups and f.g. free abelian groups) that since $\;G\;$ is a f.g. free abelian group, then there exists a (free, to be sure) basis $\;g_1,...,g_n\;$ of $\;G\;$ and integers $\;m_1,...,m_n\;$ such that $\;m_1g_1,...,m_ng_n\;$ is a basis of $\;H\;$ . In fact, the integers $\;m_i\;$ also fulfill several divisibility conditions, but we don't care about that now.

Thus, if $\;x+H\in G/H\;$ , we get that

$$m_1\cdot\ldots\cdot m_n(x+H)=m_1\cdot\ldots\cdot m_n x+H=H\;\;\;\implies $$

$\;G/H\;$ is torsion, and since  it is f.g. it is then finite.